# Laravel Nginx Query String Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, query-string, server-configuration

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and Nginx and works fine on my development server.

For example:

```
http://example.com/results?page=2
```

Development Server

```
LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage(); // returns 2
Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(); // returns 2
$request->input('page'); // returns 2
```

But in production server

```
LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage(); // returns 1
Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(); // returns 1
$request->input('page'); // returns null
```

**Production Server Configuration**

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/laravel/public;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location @rewrite {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?_url=$1;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

**Development Server Configuration**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    root /var/www/html/laravel/public;

    index       index.html index.htm index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?_url=$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize=52428800 \n post_max_size=53477376 \n memory_limit=536870912";
        fastcgi_param  APPLICATION_ENV development;
        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What changes should I make in server nginx configuration?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved!

I needed to make some corrections as there were two `fastcgi_pass` in  `location ~ \.php$ {}` so had to change

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

To

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

and modify `try_files` in `location / {}` hence had to change

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

To

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. By using try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; in the location / block solved my problem