# Nginx directives not running concurrently

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Some links on the site are sent with Ajax, and the ".php" extension is not available at the end of these links.
E.g; https://panel.example.com/app/controller/ajax/collect

At the same time, there is no ".php" suffix at the end of the site-wide pages.

I am able to send data without the ".php" at the end with Ajax. Like this;

```
try_files $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
```

it works. However, `rewrite` does not work with the above code:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?cmd=$1 last;
```

Sample link: https://panel.example.com/detail/prd1234

As a result, the above codes are correct and working but not working at the same time. How can I run these two codes at the same time?

[Full conf. file content](https://pastebin.com/03s90FQu)

Server: Nginx 1.18

Comment: It is hard to tell what the problem is, based on the information you gave. can you please add more of your ngnix config? Like the location block(s) both are in. Also what do you mean with: "How can I run these two codes at the same time?"

Comment: Hi @DennisvandeHoef , I shared the whole configuration file by updating the question. I want to say "_at the same time_"; When I add the two code structures in the question to the configuration file at the same time, one works while the other becomes passive. That's why I asked to work at the same time. Probably `if/else` command is needed but I can't do it because I don't have Nginx knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, where in the code would you add the 2 rewrites, or the try_files?

Comment: I'm adding it to the bottom of the file, [like this](https://pastebin.com/tMPeG8xn)

Comment: did you try to swap the lines? just a maybe.

Comment: @YılmazDurmaz Yes but it didn't work.

Comment: check this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252125/laravel-nginx-query-string-parameters). it might help a bit

Comment: @YılmazDurmaz Thank you, I'll try the answer to the other question for myself.